# Attempting to "Project to This PC" causes a BSOD

Tags: bsod, bluetooth, external-display, display-driver

I'm trying to project from my desktop PC to my laptop (Dell XPS 13, 2018) so that I can use it as a third display. However, every time I put in the pin to connect to the laptop over Bluetooth, it BSODs with the error `DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL`, stating the cause of the crash as `Qcamain10x64.sys`.

This happens each time I attempt to connect it as another display, without fail. I have updated the "Killer Wireless" driver, as well as making sure that all Bluetooth drivers are up-to-date. My desktop is running Windows 10 LTSB, while my laptop is running Windows 10 Pro. What can I do to make this work without crashing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up uninstalling the Killer Wireless driver, using a generic wireless driver instead. This has fixed my issue, and so far I've experienced no issues in terms of either Wi-Fi or Bluetooth.